# Monitoring chrome.storage throttle limits

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm using [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea) in an extension and would like to avoid triggering runtime errors due to exceeding one of the [documented throttles](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync) for either the sync or local stores. (things like `QUOTA_BYTES`, `QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM`)

My first choice would be to intercept these errors prior to a runtime error being generated; alternatively I could track usage on the extension side and try to avoid triggering them.

This feels like an issue that someone must have addressed, but I can't seem to find any solutions - any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample of the solution I'm going with (using Angular, so there are [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) in here), although having to regex the `chrome.runtime.lastError` value is pretty ugly IMO:

```
var service = {
  error: function(lastError) {
    if((lastError) && (lastError.message)) {
      var errorString = lastError.message;
      if(/QUOTA_BYTES/.test(errorString)) {
        return true;
      } else if(/QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM/.test(errorString)) {
        return true;
      } else if(/MAX_ITEMS/.test(errorString)) {
        return true;
      } else if(/MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR/.test(errorString)) {
        return true;
      } else if(/MAX_SUSTAINED_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_MINUTE/.test(errorString)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
  write: function(key, value) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var data = {};
    data[key] = value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set(data, function() {
      if(service.error(chrome.runtime.lastError)) {
        deferred.reject('Write operation failed: ' 
            + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      } else {
        deferred.resolve();
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
};
return service;
```